# JDBC SQL Server Unable to Establish SSL Connection

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have searched quite awhile on this but have not found out a solution yet, I am currently trying to establish a connection to SQL Server

```
Connection con = ds.getConnection
```

but am getting this exception:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: Broken pipe ClientConnectionId:8fb783f6-2790-44e9-b459-18238edd23ff"
```

This is due to the driver being unable to establish a SSL connection.

I have been able to verify that I am able to ping and view the database without any issues but somehow still getting this error.

The cause as listed is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: Broken pipe ClientConnectionId:8fb783f6-2790-44e9-b459-18238edd23ff"
```

For the same reason as above, not able to establish the SSL connection.

In context.xml I have listed:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/sqlazure"
auth="Container"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxIdle="30"
username="username"
password="password
url="jdbc:sqlserver://axpert.database.windows.net:1433;database="db";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate="database";loginTimeout=30"
removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
logAbandoned="true" />
```

I am obtaining the datasource like so:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/sqlazure");
```

So encrypt is set to true as well.  I was not seeing this issue before and the only thing I can think of is that I did install Android Studio recently, not sure if this messed up the Java settings somehow ?

I am using Eclipse Oxygen June 2017, Java 1.8.0_141, Tomcat 8.5

Answer (score 1):

For those who may have seen the same issue, I was able to resolve this by upgrading the SDK to 1.8.0_141 and pointing Eclipse to use the new JRE environment.  I made the mistake of leaving Eclipse pointing to the old JRE environment.

However, it was working before I updated the JDK to 1.8.0_141 from 1.8.0_77, am not sure yet what differences there are between the versions, or if there was some updates on the Azure end that required an update to at least version 1.8.0_141.  Any insights on this would be interesting to hear